# N = 1 or val in python

Tags: python, lua

In lua I can express this:

```
function f(arg)
   N = arg or 0
   print(N) 
end 

F()
F(5)

Output: 
--> 0
--> 5
```

Is there a way to do that in python... instead of:

```
arg = None
If arg: 
   N = arg
else: 
   N = 0

--> n = 0 
-- set arg to 5 
--> n = 5
```

Just curious, I like the Lua 1 line implementation of that. The other one is kinda jank to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to print the default value if argument is None in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248811/how-to-print-the-default-value-if-argument-is-none-in-python)

Comment: It's the other way around: `N = arg or 0` because of short-circuiting

Comment: You can also specify the default value in the function declaration: `def f(arg = 0):`

Comment: I seam to be getting " touple index out of range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use or the other way around like this:

```
def f(arg=None):
    N = arg or 0
    print(N)

f()  # 0
f(5)  # 5
```

The second option is chosen whenever arg is False or None. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

EDIT: You are looking for next

```
N = next(iter(args), 0)
```

`args` is a tuple of all the additional parameters passed to your function. You can use `next` in combination with `iter` to iterate over those parameters and select the next/first, if it exists. If not, a default value gets assigned to N (in this case 0).
Its similar to `N = args[0] if len(args) > 0 else 0` but without the check. Some more explanation is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) for example.

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't work if the input in the function is *args. I get a out of range error

Comment: *args is a tuple of all the parameters passed to your function. What exactly do are you planning to do and how do you call your function?

Comment: I added the actual code. I'm playing around with recursion. On first run nothing is passed to args. After the first run it calls itself again and passes args.

Comment: @StevenAndrewsStudent I think you are looking for N = next(iter(args), 0).

Comment: Oh I just read your edit, thank you my man <3 that did the trick <3  can you explain what exactly that line is doing ?

Comment: Glad it worked, I've added some explanation. Let me know if something is not understandable :)